# Mongoose: Remove nested object from array element

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

Using mongoose, I have a schema with a nested array, which contains another schema, which has several discriminators, something like this.

```js
const nestedSchema = new.mongoose.Schema(
  { /* some properties */ },
  { discriminatorKey: 'type' }
);

const nestedSchemaA = new mongoose.Schema({
  objectA: {
    key1: String,
    key2: String
  },
  // further properties
});

const mainSchema = new.mongoose.Schema({
  nestedArray: [nestedSchema]
});

mainSchema.path('nestedArray').discriminator('typeA', nestedSchemaA);
/* Further discriminators here */

const MainData = mongoose.model('MainData', mainSchema);
```

Now I'm trying to `$unset` the `objectA` property for one of the objects in the nested array. I have tried a few things, which either don't do anything or keep `objectA` as an empty array rather than deleting it.

This here doesn't change the data, even though I would expect it to delete `objectA`.

```js
await MainData.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.params.mainId, 'nestedArray._id': req.params.id, 'nestedArray.type': 'typeA' },
  { $unset: { 'nestedArray.$.objectA' } }
);
```

This here deletes the properties of `objectA`, but keeps `objectA` itself as an empty object.

```js
await MainData.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.params.mainId, 'nestedArray._id': req.params.id, 'nestedArray.type': 'typeA' },
  { $unset: {
    'nestedArray.$.objectA.key1': 1,
    'nestedArray.$.objectA.key2': 1,
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong and what is the correct way to achieve this?

### Edit:

I'd also be happy to simply set `objectA` to `null`, but for some reason this also doesn't work.

```js
await MainData.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: req.params.mainId, 'nestedArray._id': req.params.id, 'nestedArray.type': 'typeA' },
  { 'nestedArray.$.objectA': null }
);
```

I know the issue is not the matching clause, since I am able to find the right array element and update `key1` and `key2` individually.
Also, unsetting `objectA` or setting it to `null` used to work, before I switched to discriminators, so I suppose that they have something to do with the problem.

### Edit 2:

As requested, here is some sample data. I have added some fields to make the example more clear.

```json
{
  "_id": ObjectId('313233343536734989301111'),
  "nestedArray": [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId('313233343536734989302222'),
      "type": "typeA",
      "objectA": {
        "key1": "123",
        "key2": "456"
      },
      "message": "objectA is set"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId('313233343536734989303333'),
      "type": "typeA",
      "message": "Notice that objectA is not set. This is the result I am looking for"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId('313233343536734989304444'),
      "type": "typeB",
      "foo": "bar"
    },
  ],
  "some": "more data in main model"
}
```

Comment: I have tried unsetting another field other than `objectA`, which interestingly works. I guess the issue is with `objectA` being an object.